# getelementbyid onclick gives undefined after calling a function

Tags: javascript, html

I made this small test with 5 buttons ( now only 4 are considered ) . I don't have a lot of experience with javascript , and trying to change a variable using getelementbyid and a function , the only thing I got is an undefined number . I'm quite sure the  button side is right , but I'm not sure about the function .

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <style>
    body {
        overflow    : hidden;
        padding     : 0;
        margin      : 0;
        background-color: #BBB;

    }
    #AdvancedButton1
    {
        border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    #AdvancedButton2
    {
        border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    #AdvancedButton3
    {
        border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    #AdvancedButton4
    {
        border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    #AdvancedButton5
    {
        border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    #info {
        position    : absolute;
        top     : 0px;
        width       : 100%;
        padding     : 5px;
        text-align  : center;
    }
    #info a {
        color       : #66F;
        text-decoration : none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="info">
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div> 
    <button id="AdvancedButton1" type="button" name="" value="" style="position:absolute;left:896px;top:14px;width:102px;height:138px;z-index:1;" >
    <div style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px"><b>UP</b></span></div>
    </button>
    <button id="AdvancedButton2" type="button" name="" value="" style="position:absolute;left:896px;top:327px;width:102px;height:138px;z-index:2;">
    <div style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px"><b>DOWN</b></span></div>
    </button>
    <button id="AdvancedButton3" type="button" name="" value="" style="position:absolute;left:720px;top:181px;width:138px;height:102px;z-index:3;">
    <div style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px"><b>LEFT</b></span></div>
    </button>
    <button id="AdvancedButton4" type="button" name="" value="" style="position:absolute;left:1028px;top:181px;width:138px;height:102px;z-index:4;">
    <div style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-size:19px"><b>RIGHT</b></span></div>
    </button>
    <button id="AdvancedButton5" type="button" name="" value="" style="position:absolute;left:896px;top:181px;width:102px;height:105px;z-index:5;">
    <div style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#DC143C;font-family:'Arial Black';font-size:27px">FIRE</span></div>
    </button>
    <script>

        var outputEl    = document.getElementById('result');
        var arrow;

        document.getElementById("AdvancedButton1").onclick = function(){
            funarr('1');
        }
        document.getElementById("AdvancedButton2").onclick = function(){
            funarr('2');
        }
        document.getElementById("AdvancedButton3").onclick = function(){    
            funarr('3');
        }
        document.getElementById("AdvancedButton4").onclick = function(){
            funarr('4');
        }


        function funarr(value){

            arrow = value ;
        }

        outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> '
            + arrow ;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

what's I'm doing wrong?
at the end there's the  tag , but the post is not formatted well ( I don't know why ) and the tag is hidden

Comment: What does all that CSS have to do with this question? Please try to include only relevant code.

Comment: HTML needs to be indented 4 spaces to be formatted, otherwise it will be treated as inline HTML in your post text. Use the `{}` tool in the editor toolbar to mark code in your posts.

Answer (score 3):

And funar should be:

```
function funarr(value){
     arrow = value ;
     outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> '
            + arrow ;
}
```

And indeed you don't need the global `arrow` variable

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the `arrow` variable to set the `innerHTML` property, that doesn't link the variable to the content of the element, it just uses the current value of the variable. Changing the variable later on doesn't change the content of the element.

You need to change the content of the element when you have a new value to put in it:

```
function funarr(value){
  arrow = value;
  outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> ' + arrow;
}
```

The `arrow` variable is however not needed at all, as you can use the parameter directly:

```
function funarr(value){
  outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> ' + value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("AdvancedButton1").onclick = function(){
            funarr('1');
        }
```

Should be:

```
var thisClickyThing = document.getElementById("AdvancedButton1");
thisClickyThing.addEventListener('click', function(){
    funarr('1');
});
```

VERY quick example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/STU5x/ (note that only UP works)

Comment: While that may be a more "modern" way to do it, the old way should still work.

Comment: Your `outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> ' + arrow;` bit also needs to be inside the `funarr()` function